# Incrementing a global variable inside of a function - Python

Tags: python, function, return, global-variables, increment

```
p1_wins = 0
p2_wins = 0

def my_function(p1_wins, p2_wins, p1_answer, p2_answer)
    if p1_answer > p2_answer:
        print('Player 1 Won the Round')
        p1_wins += 1
    elif p1_answer < p2_answer:
        print('Player 2 Won the Round')
        p2_wins += 1

while True:
    if p1_wins == 3:
        print('Player 1 Wins')
    if p2_wins == 3:
        print('Player 2 Wins')

    p1_answer = input()
    p2_answer = input()

    my_function(p1_wins, p2_wins, p1_answer, p2_answer)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to increment the p1_wins and p2_wins variables without using a global statement inside of my function. As I'm trying to refrain from the bad practice of accessing global variables from inside a function. When executing this code the program runs fine, but doesn't add 1 to the wins variable. Trying to create a simple game and using a function verify who won the round and then increment there wins variable. Then once # of wins hits a certain number the game is over. Not sure if using a function here is even the best way to write this. Appreciate any help Thanks!

I thought about returning a boolean value and then using that to increment the wins, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that. What comes to mind for me is to use an if statement on the return value of the function. For instance if the function returns True then p1_wins += 1 and if False p2_wins += 1. Otherwise I know it works fine if I get rid of the function all together. Although, this would defeat the purpose of the function.

Answer (score 0):

A very minimal change would be to return the updated `p1_wins` and `p2_wins` as a tuple, and update the values in your loop accordingly:

```
def my_function(p1_wins, p2_wins, p1_answer, p2_answer):
    if p1_answer > p2_answer:
        print('Player 1 Won the Round')
        p1_wins += 1
    elif p1_answer < p2_answer:
        print('Player 2 Won the Round')
        p2_wins += 1
    return p1_wins, p2_wins

p1_wins = 0
p2_wins = 0

while True:
    if p1_wins == 3:
        print('Player 1 Wins')
    if p2_wins == 3:
        print('Player 2 Wins')

    p1_answer = input()
    p2_answer = input()

    p1_wins, p2_wins = my_function(p1_wins, p2_wins, p1_answer, p2_answer)
```

Comment: Ahh Thank You! Was struggling with this for a bit.